# Getting an error while trying to access nested objects in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I  am retrieving JSON  data from an API and then storing it in state and when I try to access the data using `this.state` (eg i write `this.state.DetailData.title`) it works fine but when I try to access the nested data (eg `this.state.DetailData.location.address`) of the same object it throws me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Caro from './Carousel'
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Col
} from 'reactstrap';


class Detail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)

  {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      DetailData: []
    }

  }




  componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://api.kloh.in/kloh/external/v1/activity/AID180917200010526C8LFJ4MEIE9CWGXZG4', {
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {

        this.setState({
          DetailData: data.response
        })
        console.log(typeof(this.state.DetailData));

      })
  }




  render() {

    return ( 
    <div>

      <Caro / >

      <Container >
      <Row >
      <Col xs = "12" sm = {{size: 8, offset: 2 } md = {{size: 8, offset: 2}} >

      < div >
      <h1> {this.state.DetailData.title} <h1> 
      <h1> {this.state.DetailData.location.address} </h1>    {/*getting error here*/}
      <hr/>
      <h6> {this.state.DetailData.description} </h6>    

      </div>

      </Col>

      </Row> 
      </Container>

 
      </div>
    );



  }

}

export default Detail;
```

Comment: Can you do console.log(this.state.DetailData); and share the data

Comment: log the data to see if you are not misspelling something or even if the property `location.address` is exists or not ????

Comment: The whole DetailData object is displayed

Comment: @hadi could you add the JSON or console output to the question please?

Comment: You need to wait for the component to fetch data before using it in the render method. Try to add a flag variable **isLoaded** to state having default value set to false and then set it to true once the data is fetched in the **componentDidMount** method and then conditionally render bases on that **isLoaded** .  Read the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

Comment: Thanks everyone it worked as i have applied one of the methods described in answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the component is mounted your data are not yet fetched so the this.state.DetailData is an empty object and the this.state.DetailData.location is indeed undefined.

To solve this problem you can try checking if the object exists before displaying it. Something like this:

```
{this.state.DetailData.location ? this.state.DetailData.location.address : ""}
```

You should also check why you define the DetailData as an array when you initialise your component but seem to be expecting an object instead.

```
this.state = {
  DetailData: [] // this should be DetailData: {} or DetailData: null
}
```

Comment: If this were the case, other attempts to access the fields (e.g., `this.state.DetailData.title`) would fail as well.

Comment: @PetrBroz I think this is the case. DetailData.title is undefined but doesn't throw an error because DetailData exists. But DetailData.location doesn't yet exist and trying to access a nested property throws an error.

Comment: Look at the actual API the user is calling (https://api.kloh.in/kloh/external/v1/activity/AID180917200010526C8LFJ4MEIE9CWGXZG4). One of the `location` fields there is `null`. That is the reason.

Comment: But I agree that the code would likely cause issues due to the pending fetch result, too.

Comment: This might be true, but irrelevant. If the data are not available to the component when it mounts then the DetailData.location.address will always throw an error...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://api.kloh.in/kloh/external/v1/activity/AID180917200010526C8LFJ4MEIE9CWGXZG4, sometimes the `location` field there is null so you'll need to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding this scenario I would suggest you to use

```
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get
```

it is a much cleaner way to get the value for deeply nested property. Install lodash and import it then use

```
import React from 'react'
import Caro from './Carousel'
import {
 Container,
 Row,
 Col
} from 'reactstrap';

import _ from 'lodash';

class Detail extends React.Component {
 constructor(props)

{
super(props)
this.state = {
  DetailData: []
}

}




componentDidMount() {

fetch('https://api.kloh.in/kloh/external/v1/activity/AID180917200010526C8LFJ4MEIE9CWGXZG4', {
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {

    this.setState({
      DetailData: data.response
    })
    console.log(typeof(this.state.DetailData));

  })
}




render() {

return ( 
<div>

  <Caro / >

  <Container >
  <Row >
  <Col xs = "12" sm = {{size: 8, offset: 2 } md = {{size: 8, offset: 2}} >

  < div >
  <h1> {_.get(this.state, 'DetailData.title', 'any_default_value_for_title')} <h1> 
  <h1> {_.get(this.state, 'DetailData.location.address', 'any_default_value_for_address')} </h1>    {/*getting error here*/}
  <hr/>
  <h6> {_.get(this.state, 'DetailData.description', 'any_default_value_for_description')} </h6>    

  </div>

  </Col>

  </Row> 
  </Container>


  </div>
);



  }

  }

  export default Detail;
```

This is adding one more library to your project. But this is the clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your render method is running before de ComponentDidMount function so the initial state is being used there, where the `this.state.DetailedData` is an empty array so `this.state.DetailData.location` is undefined and you can not check the `this.state.DetailData.location.address` without getting an error so you need to check whether it exists the location or not

Answer (score 0):

using react,react-redux, useSelector

useSelector is the hooks alternative to mapstatetoprops

i found that i could not map nested object
'typeerror cannot read property of undefined'

my data looks like this

```
orderDetails:{loading:_, error:_, order:{etc:_,items:[...,{etc:_}]}
```

error

```
useEffect(()=>{...dispatch()},[])
const orderDetails = useSelector(state=>state.orderDetails)
const {order, loading, error}= orderDetails;
```

worked by using useSelector and selecting deeper state vs destructuring

```
const order = useSelector(state=>state.orderDetails.order)
```